# VSCode/Win10 - Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH

Tags: node.js, windows, visual-studio-code, .net-core

**To reproduce:**

---

- Use my Windows 10 PC to open VSCode
- Create a Hello World js file
- Launch as node application from the VSCode Debugger view

Produces error: `Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH`

**Given:**

---

- My launch.json:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Build",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/build.js",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "sourceMaps": false
        }
    ]
}
```

- I have moved nodejs to within 2048 characters of my PATH variable.
- I have restarted my computer.
- I have restarted VSCode.

*From both CMD and the Integrated Terminal (sysnative/cmd):*

- `PATH` contains `D:/Program Files/nodejs`
- `where node` returns `D:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe`

*From the Google Developer Console:*

- `process.env.PATH` contains `D:/Program Files/nodejs`
- Running the following code produces `D:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe`:

```js
(function(){
    const cp = require('child_process');
    const env = Object.assign({}, process.env, {
        ATOM_SHELL_INTERNAL_RUN_AS_NODE: '1',
        ELECTRON_NO_ATTACH_CONSOLE: '1'
    });
    const result = cp.spawnSync('where', ['node'], {
        detached: true,
        stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', process.stderr],
        env,
        encoding: 'utf8'
    });

    console.log(result.stdout);
})();
```

**Additional**

---

- Also .NET-Core applications behave identically - terminal and cmd works, `dotnet` is on the path, but Launch from VSCode debugger view fails to find CLI Tools on the path.
- Attaching to an existing `dotnet` process produces a different error:
  `Please set up the launch configuration file for your application. command 'csharp.listProcess' not found`
- Not sure if related, but F12 for jumping to declaration is unresponsive.

**Update**

I've been doing some debugging, and it looks like the following code produces `Command Failed: echo test`:

```js
require('child_process')
.execSync('echo test', {cwd: workspaceRoot, env: process.env});
```

Under the hood, it winds up calling

```js
require('child_process')
.spawnSync('cmd', ['/s', '/c', '"echo test"'], {cwd: workspaceRoot, env: process.env});
```

The command it builds under the hood is `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /s /c "echo test"` which I tested and does indeed print `test`.

The `spawnSync` call reveals that the exit code was `3221225477`.

In fact, every time I use child_process to execute something via cmd, the exit code is 3221225477. I can get spawnSync to start other processes aside from cmd, though. This works:

```js
require('child_process')
.spawnSync('node', ['build.js'], {cwd: workspaceRoot, env: process.env});
```

Comment: If you are using Node 6.9+, does changing 'type' to 'node2' work?

Comment: @RobLourens `node2` behaves identically, same error. `node -v` gives `v6.9.5`.